# Can you please identify these two assemblies, dark grey, dark red, yellow, and tan plus Technic treads with large orange pieces?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Set assemblies 1

[image]

Set assemblies 2
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the top image you have parts of [7656-1: General Grievous Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/7656-1/General-Grievous-Starfighter) and 
[7669-1: Anakin's Jedi Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/7669-1/Anakin-s-Jedi-Starfighter).

In the second image you have parts of 
[7706-1: Mobile Defense Tank](https://brickset.com/sets/7706-1/Mobile-Defense-Tank)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Out of curiosity, did you happen to own the kits, or something you had seen in the past?  Thanks again

Comment: @pete I have a good memory, and build with the Exo-Force set before.